# put username and password on wsdl in mule

Tags: spring-security, mule

I use mule-standalone-3.3.0 CE. I create pattern web service proxy, and my config:

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="WebService"
    wsdlLocation="http://www.tset.com/WebService/Tse.asmx?WSDL"
    inboundAddress="http://localhost:8084/test"
    outboundAddress="http://www.tset.com/view" />
```

I want to put username and password on my new wsdl (`http://localhost:8084/test?wsdl`).
What is the best way for do that?
I know some way such as: "using spring security" but I don't know this way is good or no.
and I have a problem about spring security:
I don't know how to set SoapUi?  I don't know how to send authentication headers within my soapUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service pattern can be defined in an extended way that allows the definition of child elements. By using it you will be allowed to define the [security filter](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager#ConfiguringtheSpringSecurityManager-SecurityFilters) leveraging [spring security](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager#ConfiguringtheSpringSecurityManager-Example)

Your pattern configuration should look like the following:

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="WebService"
         wsdlLocation="http://www.tset.com/WebService/Tse.asmx?WSDL">
        <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8084/test" >
            <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
        <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://www.tset.com/view" />
</pattern:web-service-proxy>
```

Comment: Hi @genjosanzo, thanks for your reply, yes, I use spring security according to this page: [link](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager)
I configure setting of soapUI.
but when I create stub file from my WSDL, I recieve below error:
`Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://192.168.0.5:8084/echoService?wsdl`

Comment: That means that the authentication is working. You should configure the basi authentication headers within your SoapUI. You can find how to do so here http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/authenticating-soap-requests.html

Comment: I see this page, @genjosanzo. and I did configuration of soapUI IntelliJ Plugin.
I want to create web service in same Intelij IDE, but I had that problem and errors.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the intellij soapui plugin, but to verify the WSDL is secured properly you can try to access the url http://192.168.0.5:8084/echoService?wsdl from any browser.

Comment: Hi @genjosanzo. I access the 192.168.0.5:8084/echoService?wsdl from brower. but I can't create stub file from wsdl.